# How would you search a dictionary and print out entries with same value

Tags: python

I've been a little confused on how you would go about this,  so what would be a good way to do it. 
For Example:
If I had this as my dictionary

```
dic = [{1:'Dog', 2:'Cat'}, {1:'Bird', 2:'Rat'}, {1:'Turtle', 2:'Cat'}]
```

The value that you would be looking for is:

```
value = 'Cat'
```

And I'm trying to make the program print out each entry that has the Value of 'Cat':

```
[{1:'Dog', 2:'Cat'}, {1:'Turtle', 2:'Cat'}]
```

Comment: http://www.diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/filtering_lists.html

Comment: right, so, `dic` is not a dictionary.  it's a list.

Answer (score 3):

```
[dictionary for dictionary in dic if "Cat" in dictionary.values()]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
L = [{1:'Dog', 2:'Cat'}, {1:'Bird', 2:'Rat'}, {1:'Turtle', 2:'Cat'}]
maps = {}
for i,d in enumerate(L):
    for v in d.values():
        if v not in maps:
            maps[v] = []
        maps[v].append(i)

for k,vals in maps.items():
    if len(vals)>1:
        print(k)
```

Output:

```
Cat
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just doing this once, just loop over the values:

```
results = []
for d in dic:
    if value in d.values():
        results.append(d)
```

This gives you a list of all of the dicts in `dic` that have a value that matches `value`.

If you understand comprehensions, you can condense this to:

```
results = [d for d in dic if value in d.values()]
```

For example:

```
>>> value = 'Cat'
>>> results = [d for d in dic if value in d.values()]
>>> results
[{1: 'Dog', 2: 'Cat'}, {1: 'Turtle', 2: 'Cat'}]
```

---

If you're doing this a million times, or even 10 times, it will be both simpler and more efficient to build the right data structure. If you want to look up X and get Y simply and quickly, you want a dict with those Xs as keys, and those Ys as values. So:

```
value_map = {}
for d in dic:
    for v in d.values(): # viewvalues() in 2.7, itervalues in 2.6
        value_map.setdefault(v, []).append(d)
```

Now, the search is just:

```
>>> value_map['Cat']
[{1: 'Dog', 2: 'Cat'}, {1: 'Turtle', 2: 'Cat'}]
```

Can't get any simpler. Or faster.